# How can I get the Resonant Frequencies (Bode plot)? (Response of 2-DOF System)

Tags: matlab, frequency, amplitude, transfer-function, magnitude

I want to study the response of the system.

I want to find the resonant frequency of the sprung mass (m1) and the resonant frequency of the unsprung mass (m2).

Because I am not sure if I have understood the meaning of resonant. Let's say that we have a suspension system and we stimulated with a step response 0.1(m).

That means, for example at 1(Hz) the sprung mass (m1) vibrating at the high level? and at 10(Hz) the unsprung mass (m2) vibrating at the high level?

I've read about bode plot and I did some things as you can see below but I don't know if this is the way to find the Resonant Frequencies. Maybe FFT is what I'm looking for?

In my bode plot (Picture below):

Blue Line: The first peak corresponds to the resonant frequency of the sprung mass (m1)? and Orange Line: Τhe second peak (which is higher than the first peak of orange line) corresponds to the resonant frequency of the unsprung mass (m2)?

If yes how can I get these values? What I need to add to my code?

Can I change the units from decibel to m?

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

%% Parameters
m1 = 400;    % Sprung Mass (kg)
m2 = 40;     % Unsprung Mass (kg)
k1 = 21000;  % Suspension Stiffness (N/m)
k2 = 150000; % Tire Stiffness (N/m)
b1 = 1500;   % Suspension Damping (N*s/m)
b2 = 0;      % Tire Damping Coefficient (N*s/m)

%% Transfer Function
num1 = [(0) (0) (b1*b2) (b1*k2+b2*k1) (k1*k2)];
den1 = [(m1*m2) (m1*b1+m1*b2+m2*b1) (m1*k1+m1*k2+m2*k1+b1*b2) (b1*k2+k1*b2) (k1*k2)];
G1 = tf(num1,den1); % G1(s) = X1(s)/Xr(s)
num2 = [(0) (m1*b2) (m1*k2+b1*b2) (b1*k2+b2*k1) (k1*k2)];
den2 = [(m1*m2) (m1*b1+m1*b2+m2*b1) (m1*k1+m1*k2+m2*k1+b1*b2) (b1*k2+k1*b2) (k1*k2)];
G2 = tf(num2,den2); % G2(s) = X2(s)/Xr(s)

%% Results
figure;
step(0.1*G1,0:0.01:5);
hold on;
step(0.1*G2,0:0.01:5);
title('');
legend('m1','m2');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude (m)');
axis([]);
grid on;

figure;
bode(G1);
hold on;
bode(G2);
title('');
legend('m1','m2');
axis([]);
grid on;
```

[Reaponse, Bode Plot and 2 DOF System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4eKm.png)

Comment: I suggest that you add the image of your mass-spring-damper system  (the rightmost subplot of the figure you linked at the end of your post) at the very beginning of your post where you mention m1 and m2. I think there should be formulas to calculate the frequencies so that you do not have to read them off the plots (unless you have to). But it may then also rather be a question for [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) as I don't think this is a programming question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry I thought I should post here the question since I use matlab.I want to find the resonant frequencies in matlab (since I use matlab to study the response of my system) for my system.